# Form Authentication doesn't work with firewall's pattern property

Tags: symfony, symfony6, symfony-security

I am using symfony 6, and facing some issues while having 2 authentication firewalls.

I need one to authenticate customer users, and another one for Dashboard users. To do so I setup 2 firewalls with different pattern. But it doesn't seem to work, as when I try to reach a secured page with the 'back_office' firewall, the profiler doesn't designate the right one, and submitting the authentication just reloads the form login.

Here is my security.yaml file :

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    app_user_provider: 
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Client
            property: email
    bo_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\BoUser
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    back_office:
        pattern: ^/Dashboard
        lazy: true
        context: my_context
        provider: bo_user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: bo_login
            check_path: bo_login
            enable_csrf: true
        logout:
            path: app_logout
    customer:
        lazy: true
        context: my_context
        pattern: ^/
        provider: app_user_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: app_login
            check_path: app_login
            enable_csrf: true
        logout:
            path: app_logout
```

When I request a secured route, I am redirected to the correct form login, but in the profiler I see that the firewall name is 'customer' :
[Symfony profiler - wrong firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuIpM.png)

After submitting the login form, the page reloads and I am not authenticated. No authentication errors are shown.

If I disable the customer firewall, I am still redirected to the correct form login, but no firewall is designated in the profiler :
[Symfony profiler - no firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l29yW.png)

If I comment the pattern property on the back_office firewall, then I am redirected to the correct form login, the profiler designates the right firewall, and I am able to authenticate correctly:
[Symfony profiler - right firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEELg.png)

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Have a nice day

//UPDATE
Here is the updated yaml file, as requested by ramsey_lewis

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        back_office:
            pattern: ^/Dashboard
            lazy: true
            provider: bo_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: bo_login
                check_path: bo_login
                enable_csrf: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
        customer:
            # pattern: ^/Dashboard
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

Comment: I have the same issue. First it was because i forgot the '$' symbol at the end of my pattern, but then even connected my user is NULL. It's all related to that pattern issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I was not able to make it work. I think I am going to find a "workaround". I will either make the pattern option's job "manually", or unify the two user classes with an inheritance.

I am thinking about letting this issue open, in case someone come up with a solution, if it's in agreement with the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround after all those days, I don't know if it's the best thing to do but it work.

It's all related to the `pattern` property. I was using the same kind of pattern as you `^/login-admin` and `^/login-user`. The problem was the firewalls could only catch these 2 routes, but when I was redirected (after leaving the login form) the firewalls didnt know which one was called.

I ended up creating a pattern only for my second login form, because all the `user` routes will be behind something like `/user/profile`, `/user/item-123`...

And for my main login form (for admin firewall), I didn't set any pattern property. I just put the configuration for this specific firewall **after** the user firewall. With that, if the routes match something like `/user/*`, the `user` firewall it will be called, if it's something else not related to `/user/*`, the `admin` will be called. If the firewall can't catch anything, it will let other firewalls try to catch it

```
firewalls:
    user:
        pattern: ^/(user\/.*)|/login-user|/logout-user
       ...
    admin:
        <--- no pattern property
        ...
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thank you for your proposition. I applied your solution, except for the one firewall that gets the pattern property, I set it for the admin login (placed before the customer firewall). 
However, I get the same behaviour; When trying to login as a customer the right login page is selected, with the right firewall. And when I try to login as an admin, the right login page is selected but with the wrong firewall.

Comment: can you update the yaml file to show me?

Comment: Sure. It is done.

Comment: thanks. What logins routes do you use ? You need to add your login route into your pattern for `bo_login`, like I did.  If I delete my `|/login-user` part, it doens't work anymore. As the firewall doesn't know form_login to use, he's using `app_login` as default

Comment: I just added the login route and it works like a charm now ! Thank you so much for your help !